# Understanding page.route() in wagtail source code

Tags: django, wagtail

In **[wagtail.core.views.py](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/45b7788c6df8aaeb98d2130248b0b000d3df4d4d/wagtail/core/views.py#L12)**,

```
def serve(request, path):
    # we need a valid Site object corresponding to this request in order to proceed
    site = Site.find_for_request(request)
    if not site:
        raise Http404

    path_components = [component for component in path.split('/') if component]
    page, args, kwargs = site.root_page.localized.specific.route(request, path_components)
...
    return page.serve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`page, args, kwargs = site.root_page.localized.specific.route(request, path_components)` will invoke **[wagtail.core.models.page.route()](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/45b7788c6df8aaeb98d2130248b0b000d3df4d4d/wagtail/core/models/__init__.py#L812)**, which will further invoke `RouteResult.__init__()` in **[wagtail.core.url_routing.py](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/45b7788c6df8aaeb98d2130248b0b000d3df4d4d/wagtail/core/url_routing.py#L10)**.

**Q: why `page, args, kwargs` would be returned together by `route()`?**

According to source code, `args, kwargs` should always be `None`. I did not see anywhere in the processing we have any arguments passed in for `args, kwargs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ordinary page that's handled through the basic `Page.route` method, `args` and `kwargs` will always be empty, yes - in this case, the job of the `route` method is simply to find the correct Page object to handle the request, and the Page object is the only thing that needs to be returned.

However, specific page types can override `route` to pick up extra data during page routing - this will be passed as additional arguments to the `serve` method. The [wagtail.contrib.routable_page](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/routablepage.html) app uses this technique - it [overrides the `route` method](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/9ae4ab6084a47b31092ba6834f975c992a9fb93c/wagtail/contrib/routable_page/models.py#L97) to match against any of the URL routes defined on the page model. It then returns the matched view function, along with any extra arguments from the URL.